# Haskell delete largest number from a list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out how to create a recursive function that will find the largest element in the list and delete it then return the list. This is what i have so far but the problem is that every time i run it it returns the list without any of the values that are assigned to x.

```
deleteMax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
deleteMax  [] = []
deleteMax [x] = []
deleteMax (x:y:xs) 
    |x == y = y: deleteMax xs 
    |x >= y = y: deleteMax xs
    |x < y = x: deleteMax xs
```

Comment: You have an `x == x` condition. Probably not intended?

Comment: You write `deleteMax [x] = [x]`. But isn't `x` the largest element of `[x]`?

Comment: What should happen if the largest element is repeated? Like `deleteMax [3,1,3]`?

Comment: These two lines are not executed 
|x >= y = y: deleteMax xs
|x < y = x: deleteMax xs
because x == x is always true.

Comment: Yes sorry i made the mistake and fixed the third line and removed the sixth line.
@dfeuer if there are multiples of the same element then only one should be deleted.
when i do: deleteMax [1,2,4,4,3]
i get [1,4]

Comment: You cannot do it in one pass. `[2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3]`. Should you remove `2`? You don't know until tge very end.

Comment: Yea thats the problem i cant figure out how to make it work without deleting all off the other values. deleteMax [1,2,4,4,3] should return [1,2,4,3] but its not it is deleting every value that is assigned to x.

Comment: You could call a helper function which stores the list before the current max the max and go through the list after the current max to see if there's something bigger.

Comment: You need to pass through the list twice. How about writing two functions? One would find the maximum element and the other would remove an element equal to a given one.

Comment: I chose the `[3,1,3]` example for a reason. Do you want that to produce `[3,1]` or `[1,3]`? I imagine you probably want to delete the first or last duplicate, but maybe you want to delete one of the others...

Comment: @n.m., you can't do it in one pass, but your approach seems like overkill. There's no need to perform more than one pass-worth of comparisons. Just find the index of the element to be removed.

Comment: I see what you are saying i think deleting the first one and getting [1,3] would be the way im thinking. I am still kind of new to haskell so i am trying to learn and figure out how to implement these ideas.

Comment: @n.m. Why can't we do it in one pass?  It's not like we'd have to tie ourselves in a knot...

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson your input and output lists are on magnetic tapes and you have O(1) RAM. Ready?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't like indexing lists, but that's another option, yes.

Comment: @n.m., equivalently, you can save a zipper representing the position of the most recently encountered maximal element. The downside is that it allocates unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not your answer**

So you are a beginner and as such would like the simple solution of "how do I find the largest element in a list" followed by "how do I remove (one of the) largest element(s) in the list".  This isn't that answer but it is me avoiding a long comment while also giving you something to come back to in 3 months.

**The Lazy Way**

One solution, which @n.m. and I were sparring about in comments, is to tie the knot (Googleable term).  In this method you only need one logical pass over the list.  In this case it is basically a trick to hide the pass that constructs the result list.

The idea is that during your pass over the list you do both tasks of 1. Compute the maximum element and 2. Compare with the maximum element and construct the list.  There is nothing here that requires a monad but it can be easiest to see as part of a state monad:

```
deleteMaxState :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
deleteMaxState []       = []
```

First we handle the base cases so we have a candidate 'maximum' (`x`) for our recursive operation.

```
deleteMaxState xs@(fstElem:_) =
    let (r,(m,_)) = runState (go xs) (fstElem, notMax m)
        notMax mx v = if (mx > v) then (v:) else id
        go [] = return []
        go (x:xs) =
            do (curr,f) <- get
               when (x > curr) (put (x,f))
               f x <$> go xs
    in r
```

In the loopwe track two values the first, `curr`, is the largest observed value by this point in our traversal of the list.  The second value, `f`, is the trick - it is (a function including) the maximum value provided to the computation *after* the traversal has completed.

The magic is all here:

```
(r,(m,_)) = runState (go xs) (fstElem, m)
```

The left element of the result state `(m,_)` was our running maximum. Once the traversal ends we use that value - it becomes the right element `(fstElem, m)` and thus represents the maximum of the whole list.

We can use `f` to create thunks that populate portions of the list or just in-line construct our list as a bunch of unevaluated `cons` computations.

Making this one iota simpler, we can remove the higher-order function `f` and just have a number (untested):

```
deleteMaxState xs@(fstElem:_) =
    let (r,(m,_)) = runState (go xs) (fstElem, m)
        go [] = return []
        go (x:xs) =
            do (curr,theMax) <- get
               when (x > curr) (put (x,theMax))
               ((if x >= theMax then Nothing else Just x) :) <$> go xs
    in catMaybes r
```

Now we can see the second pass pretty explicitly not just as an unevaluated set of "some computation involving max, consed on the result" but as an actual pass via `catMaybes`.

The tying of the knot allows the programmer to write one logical traversal.  This can be nice since it requires only one pattern match and recursive call per constructor of the list elements but at the cost of reasoning about evaluation order.

Comment: Although you *use* laziness, your solution is not as lazy as it could be. For example, I would expect `deleteMax [1..]` to be `[1..]`. As soon as we know an element is not the maximal element, we can emit it. We can be lazier in some cases if we delete the *last* copy of the maximal element rather than the *first* one, as we can then emit `3:1:` if we see `3 : 1 : 3 :`, but that's up to the OP.

Comment: I suspect the trick will be to produce a list of "intermediate maxima". That is, the elements that are ever the largest seen so far. So for `[1,5,2,7,8]` we'd end up with `([1,5,2,7], [1,5,7,8])`. I'm not very good at tying knots, so I'm not sure just how to accomplish that.